# Date validation using MaskedEditExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, date, maskededitvalidator

I am using `Ajax` for `maskededitextender` as well as `javascript` for my date field. Now in that if i insert date like `12/12/2013` then it allows me to insert. But if i insert `13/12/2013` or `12/13/2013` validation occurs Date is not valid. This is happening because format of `javascript` and format of `MaskedEditValidator` conflicts with each other. My format of javascript date validator is as below

```
 var fromdatePat =  /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/;
```

and my maskededitvalidator is as below

```
 <ajax:MaskedEditValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="MaskedEditValidator2" runat="server"
 ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" Style="vertical-align:middle;" 
 CssClass="custom_validate_message" ControlToValidate="txtduedate" 
 EmptyValueMessage="Date is required" InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid" 
 Display="Dynamic" TooltipMessage="Please Insert Date" EmptyValueBlurredText="*" 
 InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Sorry Invalid Date" 
 ClientValidationFunction="txt_duedate_validate_client" 
 OnServerValidate="txt_duedate_validate_server" ValidationGroup="MKE">  
 </ajax:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Link my friend, i guess the problem is with the  format of javascript date validator.

Try this validator in the Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/LSsMc/

```
(/^(((0[13578]|1[02])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[13456789]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(02\/29\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g)
```

Why don't you use the date validator format in regular expression validator?

And in the MaskedEditExtender UserDateFormat="MonthDayYear" it works..!!

Comment: It seems that you haven't checked my full question buddy... I clearly mentioned that.... the problem is not with format... the problem is due to the validator and date format is taken combined with different format...